# Determining all the possible values of $n$ under restrictions on number of factors of $n(n+2)(n+4)$

Tags: number-theory, functions, solution-verification

> Determine all positive integers $n$ such that the number $n(n+2)(n+4)$ has at most $15$ positive divisors.

I wanted to verify my approach for the problem. It goes like this:

***My Approach:***

There can be two cases:

**Let $n$ be even.**

Now it is evident that $2|n$, $2|n+2$ and $2|n+4$

This means that $2^3|n(n+2)(n+4)$

Since we have $3$ consecutive even numbers. It is evident that either $4|(n+2)$, or $4|n$ and $4|n+4$

Suppose $4|(n+2)$, this means that there would be one more factor of $2$ than the initial number dividing the number, thus $2^4|n(n+2)(n+4)$

It is also evident that $3|n(n+2)(n+4)$

So now $n(n+2)(n+4)=2^4\cdot 3\cdot p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$

This means that $\tau (n(n+2)(n+4))=5\times 2\times (a_1+1)\times (a_2+1)\times \cdots \times (a_r+1)$.

Observe that if any of the $a_i\geq 1$, then $\tau (n(n+2)(n+4))\geq 5\times 2\times 2>15$.

$\therefore $ All $a_i=0$. Thus $n(n+2)(n+4)=2^4\times 3=48=2\times 4\times 6$, which means that $\boxed{n=2}$

Suppose $4|n$ and $4|n+4$, and since we have two consecutive factors of 4, one of them must be divisible by $8$.

Thus there are $3$ additional factors of $2$ in $n(n+2)(n+4)$.

So $n(n+2)(n+4)=2^6\cdot 3\cdot p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$

Now using the same argument as used in the previous case, we know that $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

$\therefore n(n+2)(n+4)=2^6\times 3=4\times 6\times 8$ which means that $\boxed{n=4}$.

**Let $n$ be odd.**

Now $3|n(n+2)(n+4)$. Also any two of them taken in pair are relatively prime.

Let $n(n+2)(n+4)=(3\times k)\cdot p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}\cdot q_1^{b_1}\cdot q_2^{b_2}\cdots q_s^{b_s}$

Now $k$ can be from the set $\{1, 3, 5,\ldots\}$.

Suppose $\tau (3k)\geq 4$, then $\tau (n(n+2)(n+4))\geq 4(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_r+1)(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots (b_s+1)$

We need $4(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_r+1)(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots (b_s+1)\leq 15$ or $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_r+1)(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots (b_s+1)\leq 3$.

But there would be at least one $a_i>1$ and $b_i>1$ because the numbers not divisible by three are greater than 1.

Thus $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots (a_r+1)(b_1+1)(b_2+1)\cdots (b_s+1)\geq 4$ which is contradictory.

$\therefore \tau (3k)\leq 3$. Now if $3\not | k$ and $k\neq 1$, then it is evident that $\tau (3k)\geq 4$ which doesn't satisfy our conditions.

$\therefore 3|k$. Since $\tau(3k)\leq 3$, the only possible values for $k$ are ${1,3}$ or $3k=3$ or $3k=9$. Which means the triplets can be $(1,3,5), (3,5,7), (5,7,9), (7,9,11)$ and $(9,11,13)$. This means that $\boxed{n=1,3,5,7,9}$

Considering both the cases together, we get $\boxed{n=1,2,3,4,5,7,9}$

Please check my approach for any mistakes. Also please provide an alternate solution less convoluted than this if possible.

***THANKS***

Comment: First suggestion: when $n$ is even, $2^3 \cdot 3 | n(n+2)(n+4)$, you already have 8 factors so there cannot be any other prime factors than $2, 3$.

Comment: And your proof when $n$ is even is incomplete. For example, when $4|n+2$, $2^4 \cdot 3 | n(n+2)(n+4)$ but there may be higher power of $2$ or $3$ that divides $n(n+2)(n+4)$.

Comment: I have checked by some examples that in that case, the number will not be the product of some $n$, $n+2$ and $n+4$. I have somewhere used the the fact the any pair of two of them is always relatively prime when $n$ is odd, but can't convert the idea to words. Can you please provide an argument to complete the proof?

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

As pointed out by Misha Lavrov, when $n$ is odd there's also a case where $P_n=pq$.

---

Denote $P_n=n(n+2)(n+4)$.

If $n$ is even then $2^4 \cdot 3 | P_n$. There are no other prime factors since there are already $10$ factors from $2^4 \cdot 3$. So the only possibilities for $P_n$ are: $2^4 \cdot 3^2, 2^4 \cdot 3, 2^5 \cdot 3, 2^6 \cdot 3$. And you can check easily only $P(2)=48$ and $P(4)=192$ work.

If $n$ is odd, then $n, n+2, n+4$ are pairwise co-prime. So the only possibilities for $P_n$ are: $P_n = pqr$ or $P_n=p^2 q r$ where $p, q, r$ are distinct prime numbers (since we can't have $4$ or more prime factors). And one of $n, n+2, n+4$ is either $3$ or $3^2$. So there are only a few cases to check. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: In the odd case, $P_n = pq$ is also possible for one value of $n$ :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

First consider three basic results.

(1) It is evident that $3$ is a factor of $n(n+2)(n+4)$

(2) Let $p$ be any prime dividing two of $n,n+2,n+4$, then $p$ divides the difference between these two numbers i.e. $2$ or $4$. Then $p=2$.

(3) A number expressed as a product of prime powers, $p^aq^br^c...$, has $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)...$ positive factors. Therefore $n(n+2)(n+4)$ has at most three prime factors. Furthermore, when there are three prime factors, we can only have $pqr$ or $p^2qr$.

**$n$ odd**

One of $n,n+2,n+4$ is $1,3$ or $9$ and then  $n$ is one of $1,3,5,7,9$, all of which are solutions.

**$n$ even**

Then $n(n+2)(n+4)$ has a factor $2^a3^br^c...$, where $a\ge 3,b\ge 1$. Since $(a+1)(b+1)\ge 8$ we must have $c=0$ i.e. only prime factors of $2$ and $3$.

Now $3$ can only be a factor of one of $n,n+2,n+4$ and therefore the other two numbers are unequal powers of $2$. If neither is less than or equal to $4$, then we would have $a\ge 1+3+4$ and then $2^83$ would give $18$ positive factors.

Therefore one of $n,n+2,n+4$ is $2$ or $4$ and then  $n$ is one of $2,4$, both of which are solutions.

Comment: I already knew that. I'm really sorry if my comment was not properly worded and confused you.

Comment: No probs. I've written out a proof of what you want now.